# how to distinguish tasks on events in List<sObject> in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have list of sObject that can be Task or Event:

```
List<sObject> lst=new List<sObject>();
```

I want to diplay this list in visualforce in ascending orderof activityDate (it's already done).But I want to distinguish between these two sObjects ( Event and Task) using ligntning design component. Is there any attribute like isTask or isEvent on these sobject?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard Boolean field called IsTask on the Activity object

Answer (score 0):

There is a isTask attribute on Activities.
[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm)